# Find all pdf in folder of a given year in filename

Tags: regex, macos, pdf, grep

I have a folder with thousands of pdf named according to dates like `20100820.pdf` or `20000124.pdf` etc.

In the command line, I used the following command in other projects to search for all pdf in a folder and attach a command to it, like so `ls | grep -E "\.pdf$" | [command here]`. Now I would like it to search **only those pdf** in a given folder **from the year 2010** for example. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `ls 2010*pdf` maybe?

Comment: Hi Mark Setchell, I tried it again, but it does not function. :/

Comment: Maybe you have too many documents for it to work (the shell doesn't have room to expand all the arguments). Another option might be `find . -name "2010*pdf"`

Comment: While I have in fact thousands of pdf in the given folder as you guessed rightly, the above command unfortunately does not function as it gives no output.

Comment: The code above assumes you are in the directory where the PDFs are stored, if not you would need `find $HOME/Desktop/myPDFs -name "2010*pdf"` if they are in a directory called `myPDFs` on your Desktop, for example.

Comment: Yes, Mark. You are right. I was in the folder (on a mac), but did not get anything in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, it was so easy in the end.

This solves the problem:

`ls | grep -E "\.pdf$" | grep -E "2010"`

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep -E "\.pdf$" | awk -F "." '{if ($1>20100000) print $1}'
```

This command takes all the pdfs and splits the filename, the digits in file name are then compared with 20100000. If greater then, it prints the filename.